# Demonstrating that $A(N)$, the average number of positive divisors of numbers up to $N$, is approximately $\log(N)$ with error bounded by 1

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, riemann-integration

I would like to preface this question by saying I would prefer not to use any results from the prime number theorem (or any prime factorization for that matter) for sake of understanding.

So far, I am thinking of using mainly Riemann Sums. It is clear to me that $A(N) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N} \sigma_0(i)$, however, I am having a bit more trouble trying to transform this sum into a Riemann Sum and then approximate it to be $\log(N)$ (perhaps need a refresher on Riemann Sums altogether).

Will someone please get me started?

Answer (score 1):

For an event $X$, by $[X]$ I will mean $1$ if $X$ is true, and $0$ if it isn't. Then

$$ A(N) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_0(i) = \sum_{i=1}^n |\{j : j \mid i\}| = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n [j \mid i] = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n [j \mid i] = \sum_{j=1}^n \left \lfloor \frac{n}{j} \right \rfloor, $$

and this can be approximated by a Riemann sum.

Comment: $$R_N = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{N} \sum\limits_{d \mid j} \left( \frac{N}{j} - \left\lfloor\frac{N}{j}\right\rfloor\right)$$ $$\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{N} \sum\limits_{d \mid j} 1\approx \int_{1}^{N} \left[\sum\limits_{d \mid x} 1\right]dx = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{N} \left\lfloor \frac{N}{j} \right\rfloor$$ Further, since $R_N$ is always greater than 0 but strictly less than $N$, we have that $$A(N) = \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{N} \sum\limits_{d \mid j} 1 \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{N} \left\lfloor \frac{N}{j} \right\rfloor \approx \frac{1}{N} \log(N) + C$$ Something like this?

Comment: I was thinking more of using Riemann sums to approximate $\sum_{j=1}^N \frac{N}{j}$ (which is quite standard and I see you wrote the answer without any commentary, so probably it is standard also for you).

Comment: Yeah, I redid my answer. Turns out $\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \frac{N}{j}$ can be approximated quite nicely with a Harmonic Series Expansion which comes out to be exactly $\log(N)$ with error bounded by 1.